# Why don't we expand the whole equation using polynomial interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

To form a  quadratic polynomial $y(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ through the through the three points $(x,y)=(1,4),(2,5),(3,7)$, an expression can be written:

$$y(x)=4\frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(1-2)(1-3)}+5\frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{(2-1)(2-3)}+7\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(3-1)(3-2)}$$

The question is why is the equation written like that? For example, why is the whole expression not expanded? Why not simplify some of the brackets such as $(1−2)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, just edited some more information. Hope that makes more sense?!

Comment: Just to see how $x=1,2,3$ in the three consecutive summands. I still cannot read the line before $y(x)$ in the image.

Comment: the line before the image is the question, which I inputed before the link to the image. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Because in their mind they are making you the courtesy of putting in evidence which formua they are using by not doing all the calculations on one fell swoop.

Comment: Do you not think the expanded form is **less** insightful than the explicit Lagrangian form?

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes it very easy to check that the proposed expression indeeds solve the interpolation problem: every term is zero at all but one interpolation point.